# mocking class with annotated methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, easymock

I have concrete class that I want to mock. There are several annotated methods with annotations. I want to create class mock but I need to preserve that annotations.

I tried easymock. It subclasses my class without problems, but does not preserve annotations.

I would like to preserve annotations in easymock. If that is impossible are there any other mocking solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer mockito which uses a different paradigm for mocking out classes.  You don't have to subclass everything like you do with easymock.

http://code.google.com/p/mockito/

The javadoc itself has a ton of information about how to utilize the library

http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2

Her is a short example from their documentation.

```
//You can mock concrete classes, not only interfaces
LinkedList mockedList = mock(LinkedList.class);

//stubbing
when(mockedList.get(0)).thenReturn("first");
when(mockedList.get(1)).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());

//following prints "first"
System.out.println(mockedList.get(0));

//following throws runtime exception
System.out.println(mockedList.get(1));

//following prints "null" because get(999) was not stubbed
System.out.println(mockedList.get(999));

//Although it is possible to verify a stubbed invocation, 
//usually it's just redundant
//If your code cares what get(0) returns then something else 
//breaks (often before even verify() gets executed).
//If your code doesn't care what get(0) returns then it should 
not be stubbed. Not    convinced? See here.
verify(mockedList).get(0);
```

So with this library you setup your tests and stub out the methods that you are interested in testing.

Hope you found this useful.

Comment: Could you provide example with class and default/nondefault constructor? I could not find any decent example with such behaviour. Yes mock() creates mock on classes but it does not call even default constructor! And does it preserve annotations on methods?

Comment: Heh, I have encountered problem that is about mockito's architecture. It does not remember exact parameters that were sent to method, it just remembers reference to that parameter :(

Comment: Have you implemented equals on your custom objects?  Within the Matcher documentation it states Mockito executes those to determine if something is equal or not.  If you need that version of equals to be different than the typical then you could setup your own matcher.  Please refer to http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html for more information about Matchers in mockito.

Comment: That is not about matchers. That is about when mockito compares arguments. Imagine you have method argument that is valid only within specific method call (argument could be changed outside method), to use it somewhere else you have to make a copy of that argument. And mockito does not copy arguments, it just stores reference to that arguments. And when it comes to verification it fails as argument differs from the expected one!

Comment: I think I'm following what you are trying to communicate, but I would not stub out my test with an object and then use that same object when running the test.  However, with that being said I am realizing that I would have to rethink my approach if I wanted to ensure that the value hasn't changed.

Comment: That issue is discussed there http://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=126

Comment: I found solution using mockito, I subclass test class and every method whose arguments I need I override and store cloned parameters in a storage.